# Is it possible to merge list properties while performing flatmap on different streams of objects in java 8?

Tags: java, java-8

I have a stream operation which is not quite doing what I want it to

Given this data structure

```
CatOwner {
    id, 
    name, 
    List <CatType>
}
```

This code

```
    List<CatOwner> catOwner = owners.stream()
               .map(CatOwnerAccount:getCatOwnerAccountDetails)
               .filter(Objects::nonNull)
               .flatMap(catOwnerFunction)
               .distinct()
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Where

```
Function<CatOwnerAccountDetails, Stream<CatOwner>> catOwnerFunction = catOwnerDetails -> getCatOwners(catOwnerDetails);
```

I would like this to give me a merged list of unique owners, combining all their cats from different sources, so rather than producing this (as it is flatmapping and then doing a distinct on objects wioth different lists) it would merge the lists

so instead of producing this

```
{ id : 1, name: Steve, cattype : [tabby, ginger] }
{ id : 1, name: Steve, cattype : [black] }
{ id : 2, name: Mandy, cattype : [tortashelle] }
{ id : 2, name: Mandy, cattype : [manx, grey] }
```

it would produce this

```
{ id : 1, name: Steve, cattype : [tabby, ginger, black] }
{ id : 2, name: Mandy, cattype : [tortashelle, manx, grey]  }
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: You might want to correct the usage of `catOwners` in the question. It's ambiguous. The ideal solution would be collecting `toMap` choosing `extAccountDetails` as the key and merging the `List<CatType>` to get the values then.

Comment: You should review your variable names. `getCatOwners` == function `catOwners`, then you have `catOwners` list, you have class `CatOwner` and as a type of the list you use `CatOwners`

Comment: It also helps if you provide a complete CatOwner class as well as as populated list with some test data.

Comment: Thanks, sorry have had a quick stab at tidying the example code.  CatOwner is a basic pojo with getters, setters etc.  But I'll fill it out if Naman's suggestion doesn't get me there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by creating an intermediate map, but it's not very pretty.

```
Collection<CatOwner> values = owners.stream()
    // blah blah, the other stuff you had
    .collect(
        Collectors.toMap(
            owner -> new Pair<>(owner.getId(), owner.getName()),
            Function.identity(),
            (a, b) -> {
                a.getTypes().addAll(b.getTypes());
                return a;
            }
        )
    )
    .values();
```

I used a `javafx.util.Pair` as the key, though any tuple class that implements equality as the combined equality of the two elements will do.

```
owner -> new Pair<>(owner.getId(), owner.getName())
```

This says that the values of the map are the `CatOwner` items themselves (that is, the map is `Pair<Id, Name>` to `CatOwner`).

```
Function.identity()
```

This says that if there is an collision (two items with the same ID and name), the way to resolve that is to add all of the types from one `CatOwner` to the other.

```
(a, b) -> {
    a.getTypes().addAll(b.getTypes());
    return a;
}
```

The result is a `Collection`, since you take all of the values of the map. If you really want/need a list, you can add the values into a new list.

```
new ArrayList<>(values);
```